# ASP.NET/IIS disabled external image reference

Tags: html, asp.net

we have an asp.net application, there is a report that contains an image in the image folder on the same server. When we export the report (in html format), and open it locally, the image is not displayed.

If I use the image url to open in a browser, it is displayed, but not when embedded in another document.

How can I fix this?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do "export" the report? What is the generated `img` source `src` in the resulting exported HTML? Is it a static `src`, vs. set by `Javascript`? vs. `css`, etc. - at which point, it maybe using relative paths that don't exist in your local (desktop) environment.

Comment: It's using absolute path, like this: <td><img src="https://www.our-server/Image/logo.png" alt="welcome" /></td>

Comment: Is there a protocol (`http/s`) in that? As it stands, it _looks_ like a relative path and unless you saved all the resources of the page, like what browsers will do/ask when saving a web page using a browser, then your desktop doesn't have such a path.